# Using DirectoryServices.AccountManagement, how do I get the e-mail address of an active directory security group?

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I have a security group (pictured below) in active directory that has an e-mail address associated with it.  How do I get the e-mail address of the group?  The `GroupPrincipal` object does not have any e-mail address properties on it.

This is how I am retrieving all the groups:

```
using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(DirectoryContextType, Domain)) {
    using (var groupSearcher = new GroupPrincipal(context)) {
        using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(groupSearcher)) {
            foreach (GroupPrincipal group in searcher.FindAll()) {
                //How do I get the e-mail address?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Security Group]

Comment: @Anon - The group has an samaccountname active directory property.  Searching for the objects filtered by UserPrincipal does not return the object since it's a group.  The code I gave above retrieves the group, but, I don't have access to the e-mail address on the object.

Comment: @JustinHelgerson you can cast the group members as `UserPrincipal` because they share an interface; see my answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this from Account Management you will need to [make a new class that exposes that property](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/118122/How-to-use-AD-Attributes-not-represented-in-UserPr).

```
[DirectoryObjectClass("group")]
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
public class GroupPrincipalsEx : GroupPrincipal
{
    public GroupPrincipalsEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context) { }

    public GroupPrincipalsEx(PrincipalContext context, string samAccountName)
        : base(context, samAccountName)
    {
    }

    [DirectoryProperty("mail")]
    public string EmailAddress
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("mail").Length != 1)
                return null;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("mail")[0];

        }
        set { this.ExtensionSet("mail", value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unable to cast object of type ...GroupPrincipal to type GroupPrincipalsEx

Answer (score 7):

I just wanted to add this here because I think it might be helpful. 
The account management library is great for quickly doing things like resetting passwords on AD users or getting common properties. But it definitely doesn't have all of them. 
What I do is get the Underlying directory object, like so...

```
// Pretend you have a groupprincipal object called 'group' 
// This will get all of the properties of that group object not accounted for in 
// System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement
DirectoryEntry groupDE = group.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry();
// We all know that a distro group in AD will have at least 1 email address. 
// However, A
// security group will have 0, and since the mail property is of type
// PropertyValueCollection, if you try to access the first member of the collection
// and it has no length, an exception will be thrown. The following code 
// accounts for this problem. 

// Get the mail attribute of the AD object 
PropertyValueCollection group_email_addresses = groupDe.Properties["mail"];
// Make sure there is at least one address
if (group_email_addresses.Count > 0){
   // knowing that you have at least one address, you can access the first entry or 
   // loop and grab all entries on a property, depending on the appropriate use case
   Console.WriteLine(group_email_addresses[0]); 
}
```

// This concept can be applied to all Principal Objects. Just look for the 
// GetUnderlyingObject() method to get started!

Answer (score -2):

You need to cast everything as type `UserPrincipal`:

```
var mailList = new List<MailAddress>();
var adDomain = "yourdomain";
var adGroup = "yourgroup";

using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, adDomain))
{
    using (var groupContext = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, adGroup))
    {
        mailList = groupContext.GetMembers(true)
                               .Cast<UserPrincipal>()
                               .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EmailAddress) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.DisplayName))
                               .Select(x => new MailAddress(x.EmailAddress, x.DisplayName))
                               .ToList();
    }

}

return mailList;
```

Comment: @Hill perhaps your account doesn't have access to any of the other members in that AD group.